# How can I resolve cyclic dependency in Spring

Tags: java, spring

how can i resolve cyclic dependency in spring .when we have a class A has a dependency on class B and class B has a dependency on C so how can resolve these problem in java(Annotation based) using spring

Comment: define C as a bean.. then autowire(any form) C on B.. then autowire B on A.. Of course define B and A as bean tooo

Comment: I am missing how this is cyclic?  A depending on B, B depending on C is quite natural.  Please explain further,  or post the error spring is giving.

Comment: My question is that suppose class B as injected in class A and class A is injected in class C at that time some how Class A is not initialized  then makes a problem. i want that solution using initializingbean is a right option to override its method afterPropertiesSet().

Comment: @Rajeev please clarify directly in the question, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Cyclic dependency possible on Spring through Setter Injection you can see in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_d7VWtDtaA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rajeev, what you have explained is not a cyclic dependency.  You must create A, B, and C as Spring Beans and let Spring manage the related dependencies.

To be clear, a cyclic dependency is where A depends on B, B depends on C, but C depends on A.  So what to create first in this case?  You can't create A because B is not created yet.  You can't create B, because C is not created yet.  And you can't create C because A is not created yet.  So Spring stops.

In your case: A depends on B, B depends on C.  So now what?  Spring says: I will create C first.  Then I will create B, and finally I will create A.

This is possible because Spring will create all the bean definitions first.  Then when beans are created, Spring understands the wiring, and builds beans in the correct order to resolve dependencies.

I created a small project which simulates your condition, both how you describe the problem, and later how you responded in the comments.  Never a problem!  Spring can manage both scenarios you described without issue.  I implemented InitialingBean to hook into the creation, to show the order the beans are created in.

```
@Component
public class A implements InitializingBean {

@Autowired
private B b;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "My name is "+name+"; b name is "+b.getName();
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Creating A");
    System.out.println("B name="+b.getName());
}

}



@Component
public class B implements InitializingBean {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "B [name=" + name + "]";
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Creating b");
}

}



@Component
public class C implements InitializingBean {

@Autowired
private A a;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "My name is "+name+"; a name is "+a.getName();
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Creating c");
    System.out.println("A name="+a.getName());
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using the [@Lazy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotation in your constructor, like this:

```
@Component
public class C {
    private final A a;

    @Autowired
    public C(@Lazy final A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

This makes your A bean initialize only when it's actually really required, not right at the application start up when it isn't ready yet.

Answer (score 3):

First let me claim that circular dependencies are bad. No matter wether you use Spring or not. You should refactor you code it order to get rid of them.

Now the solution to your problem: As far as I know, Spring will fail to handle circular dependencies only when you use constructor injection. So when you let spring inject this dependency by property- or setter-injection it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), let me show you:

> My question is that suppose class B as injected in class A...

**BeanA**

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BeanA {

    @Autowired
    BeanB b;

}
```

> ...and class A is injected in class C...

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BeanC {

    @Autowired
    BeanA a;

}
```

while B is as simple as

**BeanB**

```
package test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BeanB {

}
```

this is my test:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class RefTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring.xml");
        BeanC c = ac.getBean(BeanC.class);
        System.out.println("is c null? " + (c == null));
        System.out.println("is c.a null? " + (c.a == null));
        System.out.println("is c.a.b null? " + (c.a.b == null));
    }

}
```

my **spring.xml** is almost empty (only `component-scan` is there):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="test" />

</beans>
```

and the result is:

```
is c null? false
is c.a null? false
is c.a.b null? false
```

Typically if injection is not working, it is because bean was not created using Spring, but `new` operator was used...

Please update your question with additional details if you are using it differently.

btw: I agree with Ian Mc, that this is not cyclic dependency