Circular reference issue in Spring Boot application
I'm encountering an issue with circular references in my Spring Boot application. Here's the scenario:
I have two beans, BeanA and BeanB, where BeanA depends on BeanB, and BeanB depends on BeanA. This circular dependency is causing initialization problems during application context startup.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
I've tried setting allow-circular-references: true in my application.yml as suggested in the Spring documentation, It is working fine.Is this good way to doing this or it might be cause the problem on production?
What's the best approach to resolve circular dependencies in Spring Boot applications? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried setting allow-circular-references: true in my application.yml as suggested in the Spring documentation.
Is it fine to use in production environment.

Does this answer your question? Circular dependency in Spring

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804237/how-can-i-resolve-cyclic-dependency-in-spring
